# Can .net 4.5.1 reference a .net 4.8 dll?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am maintaining a WinForms app written in .net 4.5.1. We have an updated API dll app that was produced in 4.8. Initially, the "drop it in" version didn't work on the final product, so I'm trying to re-reference and rebuild. Yes, 4.8 is already on the dev machine, but the project that references the new dll won't build. Is there anything else special I need to do? I get lots of search results on migration from old to new, but I haven't seen anything about the old referencing the new. Thanks in advance for any assistance and/or pointers. My search fu is failing.

Comment: 4.5.1 is end of life. You should upgrade your application target.

Comment: Right click on your project > Properties > Application > General > Target Framework > Change it to last version

Comment: If I had permission and the ability to upgrade, I would. But alas... I have neither. I'm pretty sure there' s documentation that says this is not allowed, I just need to either find it and send it to the powers that be, or find a solution that doesn't involve upgrading the main project(s).